# Excel Form can't show multiline textbox

Tags: excel, forms, multiline

Using Excel with the built-in Form tool to assist with data entry, I want multiline textboxes for a couple of the fields, but I can't see how to achieve it.

[image: Excel, showing tabular data and the multiline issue of the Form]

In standard sheet view, the line-break between "Yellow" and "Blue" is achieved with ALT+Enter.  In form view, although I can navigate left and right within C to access the line with "Blue" on it, I haven't found a way to display more than one of the cell's lines at a time, and I can't create line-breaks.

I like this Form feature because it does not rely on macros/VBA, but can I have multiline support?

Comment: I haven't seen a dialog editor...  The form doesn't appear when I click into a cell, it's a separate, modal window on top of the worksheet.  When you issue the Form command to Excel, it tries to read the data around the active cell as a table, and presents a form UI for it.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand that you were using a built-in function 'Form'. (I don't know this feature before) I remove my off topic comment.